# Как закрасить область справа или слева относительно кривой MSChart или как закрасить фигуру на графике?

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

Например, есть кривая на графике, мне необходимо закрасить ее область слева/справа. В Chart есть тип диаграммы 'Area', он позволяет закрасить область начиная от линейки оси ОХ до кривой, т.е. это можно сделать только относительно оси абсцисс и только начиная от линейки до кривой. Как сделать подобное для оси ординат? Чтобы можно было закрасить слева (начиная от линейки ОУ до кривой) и справа (начиная от кривой до конца ширины графика).

[image: так происходит сейчас при выставлении типа диаграммы "Area"]

А вот так хотелось бы получить:

[image: Закраска слева относительно кривой]
[image: Закраска справа относительно кривой]

Comment: @rdorn это вид для образца того, что я хочу получить. График может быть какой угодно ломаной. Значит нет возможности реализовать заливку цветом слева от кривой или справа?

Comment: перенес свои комментарии в ответ в окультуренном виде

Comment: Ну, чарт такого точно не может. Но можно попробовать поменять местами значения X и Y точек графика и применить к самому контролу чарта RotateTransform.

Comment: @Alexey оформили бы ответом, с минимальным примером для понимания

Answer (score 2):

Контрол `Chart` - стандартный контрол для стандартных графиков, и даже стандартные графики умеет отображать не все. Все что можно на нем изобразить ограничивается перечислением типа диаграмм класса `Series`, задающего набор точек для отображения. Поэтому, если вы не нашли среди предлагаемых диаграмм нужный тип, придется искать какое-то другое решение.

Исходный код данного контрола официально закрыт, поэтому даже подсмотреть как там что сделано не получится, можно конечно раскопать подробности через ILDasm или Refector, но это вроде как нарушение лицензии, да и результат не стоит времени, необходимого на эту затею.

Если графики простые, но нестандартные, то возможно проще будет нарисовать их вручную, у GDI+ инструментарий достаточно богатый для этого. В противном случае стоит попробовать поискать альтернативный контрол. Их не то чтобы очень много, но они есть, как платные, так и бесплатные, советовать какой-то конкретно не рискну.

---

DevExpress - судя по семплам на сайте не умеет того что вы хотите, да и денег стоит

[ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/samples.html) - в чистом виде тоже не похоже что умеет, но у него открыт исходный код и при желании можно добавить нужное самостоятельно в готовый каркас.

[Nevron](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/79feb4ac-dffa-4896-9e83-09c9a9b2b811) - в описании заявляют поддержку такого типа диаграмм

> 2D Area Charts including - horizontal Area orientation